# cant access var outside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var = msg
$.get('json-signup-erros.php',{},function(data){msg=data},'json');

function focushint()
{
   alert (msg) // this works
}
$("input").focus(focus);

 alert(msg) //this doesnot work
```

can anyone tall me way??

Answer (score 8):

You are making an AJAX request which is asynchronous.

`msg` will contain the value only after the request has been made.

You should put the code that uses `msg` into the Ajax request's `success` callback (the `function(data)`).

(There is the theoretical possibility to make the request synchronous using `async: false` but that is not good practice and should be used only if it's unavoidable.)

Comment: i whant to be able to get the error msg and then start the javascript,how can i do that?

Comment: @dvdx just put the Javascript you want to start into the success callback.

Comment: but i whant to get the data first and after a will to access to data in a function that call from the submit

Comment: @dvdx I don't know what you mean

Comment: i whant to load the lang and use it in all my jquray stuff

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pekka - you need to consider something like this:

```
var = msg;

$.get('json-signup-erros.php',{}, function(data, response)
{
   if(response == "success")
   {
       msg = data;
       alert(msg);
   }
   else
   {
       alert("Whoops something went wrong, please try again.");
   }
},'json');

function focushint()
{
   alert (msg); // this works
}

$("input").focus(focushint);
```

NB. I put a "success" check in the $.get... I see this all the time - you should not assume that your Ajax Http Request is going to return a 200 response! i.e. if no data get's returned due to an error (404, 500, 401) you can't alert it and you may want to warn the user that something went wrong by adding an else clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
var = msg;  

$.get('json-signup-erros.php',{}, function(data, response) 
{ 
   if(response == "success") 
   { 
       msg = data; 
       alert(msg); 
   } 
   else 
   { 
       alert("Whoops something went wrong, please try again."); 
   } 
},'json'); 

function focushint() 
{ 
   alert (msg); // this works 
} 

$("input").focus(focushint);
alert(msg); // this is still does not work
```

If you want to access the msg outside a jQuery function like focushin that will be in the same scope

Comment: Read my answer. **This is not a question of scope.** This is a question of the request not being finished at the time you do the alert.